# Transforming an element inside an SVG in Microsoft Edge Doesn't Work

Tags: css, svg, transform, microsoft-edge

For some reason Microsoft Edge doesn't allow you to do transforms on elements inside of an SVG. Fills work fine (so I know the element targeting is working) but transforms are entirely ignored. This works fine in chrome and as far as I can tell, *should* work fine in Edge too.

HTML:

```
<div class="test-container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 400" xmlSpace="preserve">
    <g id="Type">
      <g>
        <rect x="100" class="st1" id="rect1" width="100" height="100"/>
        <rect x="100" y="100" class="st1" id="rect2" width="100" height="100"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test-container {
  width: 100px;
}
#rect1 {
  fill: blue;
  transform: translate(50px);
}
#rect2 {
  fill: red;
}
```

See codepen example here: http://codepen.io/dwolfand/pen/pEzQgy

Any ideas?

Comment: internal SVG elements don't support CSS based transform on MSFT browsers yet. Use an SVG transform instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of August 31, 2016, Microsoft Edge does not support CSS transforms on SVG elements. This is however being considered by the Edge team for a future release. Given the support across other browsers, [status.microsoftedge.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/supportcsstransformsonsvg/?q=svg) lists this work as *likely*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - did you guys just find this bug seeing as it was just added yesterday or was this a know issue?

Comment: @DavidWolfand This feature request has been known for a while 

Comment: I do hope they support it, it will ruin many users' web experiences, it would be a shame edge had behavior that didn't match something that is common in most other browsers..

Comment: @Sampson do you have any status on this? Current client site svg heavy and we would need to take a decision soon if we should "support the design" in Edge or not.  Would love to get a word directly from the source :)

Comment: @Dejan.S Microsoft Edge added support for this in the January 11th build of Microsoft 10 this year. See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/supportcsstransformsonsvg/?q=svg

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to an issue I ran into with the D3.js library.  Shapes would come out filled with black, because the attribute properties that Edge generated (and no other browser) would always come out UPPERCASE, which the SVG standard doesn't support.  Inspect the elements and see if the attributes are uppercased; if so, then it's a known issue in Edge.

Comment: I am an engineer on the Edge team; if you have a reduction, please submit via http://bugs.microsoftedge.com.